# Group associative array data inside v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, lodash

I want to groupBy my "created_at" inside this associative array

heres my data:

```
{
parent:[{
  id: 1,
  childs:
  [{
    id:1,
    created_at: 2019-02-09
   },
   {
   id:2,
   created_at:2019-02-09},
   {
   id:2,
   created_at:2019-02-10}, 
  }]
}
```

I tried

```
computed: {

    chunkedParents: function(){
                return _.chunk(this.parents, 3);
            },
    groupChildCreatedAt: function(){
                return _.groupBy(this.parents, "created_at");
            }
}
```

the reason why I used chunk because i need to display only 3 parent in each row. The problem is that I cant use computed property inside this v-for loop. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `return _.chunk(this.groupChildCreatedAt, 3)`?

Comment: we can use computed inside of v-for loop are you getting any error if you did so?

Comment: @gowri I can't think of way how I will group each child after a loop, without using a `id` parameter inside a computed method